# Scala compiler library not showing in intellij community edition v15

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have the Scala and SBT plugins enabled (I tried switching off the SBT plugin as well to test) - when I import an existing Play framework project, go to "Project Structure", go to "Modules", select module, then "Dependencies" tab - I do not see the Scala Compiler library options at all over there (I have JDK8 and it is selected as the IDE project JVM and I have Scala and SBT on the computer - Scala v2.11.7 & SBT v0.13.9).  Any ideas on what I might be missing? I only see the JDK and Module source under Dependencies but no Scala compiler options.

I am familiar with the IntelliJ blog referencing how to import a play framework project: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html

Answer (score 1):

I am only showing the scala sdk in my `Global Libraries` tab in `Project Structure`.

Are you not able to build your project in IntelliJ?

Comment: no I am not - checking settings again to make sure I did not miss anything

Comment: I don't see scala-sdk anywhere else in project structure. What do you have in your
    `Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> Global Libraries`

Comment: I have scala-sdk-2.11.7 there